# Can we use the present continuous form to make a general statement?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, tenses, present-continuous

Considering it is a general statement, which of the following sentences sounds more natural?

> 1. I watch a lot of English speaking movies, because I'm always trying to
>    improve my English.
> 2. I watch a lot of English speaking movies, because I always try to improve my English.

As far as I know, the present continuous with "always" is often used to convey annoyance (e.g., in "You're always forgetting your keys!"). Can it be used in certain contexts to convey generalization and more emphasis?

Comment: The structure of *always present continuous* conveys annoyance? If you mean that it can serve that function, that's not the same as saying it's always conveying that tone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The continuous forms are used in English to convey quite a lot of subtextual implications.

The [LearnEnglishLanguageWell](http://www.learnenglishlanguagewell.com/grammar/continuous-verbs-with-always/) site gives some relevant examples:

> - John’s always losing his keys. (**annoyance**, shown by exasperated tone)
> - Mrs Smith is wonderful. She's always giving people vegetables and flowers from her garden. (**admiration**)
> - I’m forever seeing Mary on the bus these days. (could be **annoyance** or neutral, unmarked)
> - My dog‘s continually escaping from the garden. (probably **annoyance**)

Also, the continuous construction is used to talk about things which are unexpected or unplanned. Examples (again from LearnEnglishLanguageWell) are:

> - I ***always meet*** my husband at the station on Fridays after work. (a regular, planned arrangement ... no surprises: present simple used)
> - We‘***re** always **meeting*** Bill and Florence in the supermarket. (unplanned: present continuous)

The same happens in the past tense (/ past continuous):

> - Our English teacher always **organised** monthly trips to the theatre. (planned, regular: past simple)
> - Our parents **were** always **organising** surprise picnics and trips to the coast. (unexpected, irregular but iterative: past continuous)

However, in your example "I'm always trying to improve my English" - the action does not seem to be unexpected, so according to this site, it would not be recommended to use it in this way.

In the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/always) one finds a different focus:

```
We can use *always* with continuous verb forms
to refer to regular events or states, 
especially ones which are problematic or which we do not like or want
```

However, the examples it gives only reference annoyance.

In a [British Council site](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous) I found these examples

[S]omething which happens again and again: Note that we normally use always with this ['iterative'] use:

> - It's always raining in London.
> - They are always arguing.
> - George is great. He's always laughing.

***My conclusion:***

In all these examples, the continuous aspect conveys an extra nuance, compared to the simple aspect, which is more neutral. Therefore, if you want to emphasise your persistence, I think it is definitely okay to use ***I'm always trying to improve my English***. If you just want to state it as a neutral fact, then ***I always try to improve my English*** is enough.

Comment: As a native speaker, I agree that **I'm always trying to** is idiomatic in this context, and doesn't have to refer to negative things. I would use **I always try to** with reference to _repeated_ incidents. "Whenever my favourite film is shown on TV, I always try to watch it."

Comment: A fairly thorough treatment, not only of OP's question (addressed in the BC examples; this usage is termed 'iterative', and obviously 'always' must be read as 'continually' rather than 'continuously'; OP's example (1) _is_ idiomatic though the iteration must be deduced, the sentence being a deletion from say 'I'm always taking opportunities / the opportunity to improve my English') but also of other implications the present continuous can carry.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: what does your last comment mean? :) I have seen comments like "kkkkkkkkk" from  you :))

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Ok, will try to edit. Hopefully I will not make it worse...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Thanks for all the suggestions, let me know if I have done it well. I understand better and better how this site works through suggestions like yours.

Comment: I've done a substantial edit, but tried not to change either the facts or the tenor (except that I've depersonalised it, so 'I found that ...' becomes 'One finds that ...'). I've reformatted for consistency of appearance; that's hardly misquoting. I've added an attribution to one link; this is essential for accuracy (and to avoid potential lawsuits). // While 'I always try to improve my English' is grammatical, I wouldn't say it's that idiomatic. It's more of a continuing battle (for all of us) even though opportunities to learn occur at frequent if usually non-regular intervals.

Comment: Google data seems to show that 'I always try to improve my English' is more common than 'I'm always trying to improve my English', but I'd argue that this is because the people using the former are largely non-native speakers. // I can't upvote twice (but I really enjoy finding answers I consider might be provoking that thought).

Comment: Thank you for the effort you put in, I really appreciate it. As for Gngram, if you compare ["always try to improve" vs "always trying to improve"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Always+trying+to+improve%2C+always+try+to+improve&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAlways%20trying%20to%20improve%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Calways%20try%20to%20improve%3B%2Cc0) you will see that the simple aspect prevails. Having said that, I really think the continuous aspect is perfectly fine and up to the speaker!